# Adding to the asp wizard control?

Tags: asp.net

Im trying to add a button next to the next or finish buttons of an asp wizard control. Is there an easy way to do this with? I can't see anyway override a footer template.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will need to set the wizard.finishnavigationstyle wizard.startnavigationstyle and and I think it's called stepnavigationstyle For the wizard. These need to be set to a class which you write which inherits from ITemplate. It s very easy to add the buttons that you want within the method which must be implemented for the interface can'tmis.   I can give u an example if you want